# DataContext for binding a UserControl with ViewModel within DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Have a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection of ItemRecords.
- Have a TabControl that contains detailed view for all the ItemRecords in the ListView that were selected for editing.
- Each TabItem contains a UserControl ("ItemInfo") that uses ItemInfoViewModel as its VM (and, not so coincidentally, DataContext).
- ItemInfo UserControl needs to be populated with the data from the corresponding ItemRecord.

To achieve that, I'm trying to pass the ItemRecord (selected in the ListView) to ItemInfoViewModel.

Finally, **the question**: what do you think would be the best way to do this, without breaking the MVVM pattern?

The not-so-elegant way that I see (and it actually doesn't exactly follow the MVVM principles) is to have a DependencyProperty ItemRecord defined in the UserControl, provide its value via binding, and in the constructor (in the UserControl's code-behind) pass the ItemRecord to the VM (which we get by casting the DataContext).

The other problem is with how to actually pass the ItemRecord via binding.
Once I set the VM as the UserControl's DataContext, I cannot just use `{Binding}` to specify the current item in TabControl's source collection.
At the moment I am binding to the TabControl's SelectedItem using ElementName - but this doesn't sound too robust :-(

```
<localControls:TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <localControls:ItemInfo ItemRecord="{Binding ElementName=Tabs, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</localControls:TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Any good advice will be greatly appreciated!

Alex

Comment: "it actually doesn't exactly follow the MVVM principles" sure it does.   Does not the Text property of the TextBox not follow the MVVM principles?  A UserControl is concerned about the duties of the View.  It shouldn't be conducting business logic, but it certainly can expose properties that can be bound to the DataContext.

Comment: @Will: I'm afraid I haven't made myself clear on this point.
What I mean is that pushing a property value from View's code-behind to the ViewModel is not so elegant.

Comment: No, you were perfectly clear.  MVVM != no code behind.  That's my point.  MVVM is about the separation of concerns.  The View is concerned with the View.  If you aren't creating actual controls, then you are compositing controls in a UserControl.  Same difference.  If you aren't exposing public DPs in your custom Control, your'e doing it within the codebehind of your UserControl.  codebehind isn't anti-MVVM, its when you mix your business concerns with your view concerns that you are breaking the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you're not quite understanding the MVVM pattern here; you're still looking at this as the different controls talking to *each other*.  Where in MVVM, they should not be, each control is communicating with the *view model* independently of all the others.  And the view model controls (and supplies) the logic which tells the controls how to behave.

So, ideally you would have something like:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemRecord> ListViewRecords 
{
   get { ... }
   set { ... }
}

public IEnumerable<ItemRecord> SelectedListViewRecords {
{
   get { ... }
   set { ... }
}
```

The `ListViewRecords` would be bound to the `ItemsSource` property of your `ListView` (the actual properties might vary based on the specific controls you're using, I'm used to the Telerik suite at the moment so that's where my head is).  And the `SelectedListViewRecords` would be bound to the `SelectedItems` property of the `ListView`.  Then for your TabControl you would have:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyTabItem> Tabs
{
   get { ... }
   set { ... }
}

public MyTabItem SelectedTab
{
   get { ... }
   set { ... }
}
```

Again, you would bind the `Items` property to the `Tabs` and `SelectedItem` to the `SelectedTab` on your `TabControl`.  Now your view model contains all the logic, so in your `SelectedListViewRecords` you might do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemRecord> SelectedListViewRecords {
{
   get { ... }
   set 
   {
       _selectedRecords = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedListViewRecords");

       Tabs.Clear(); // Clear the existing tabs
       // Create a new tab for each newly selected record
       foreach(ItemRecord record in value)
          Tabs.Add(new MyTabItem(record)); 
   }
}
```

So the idea here is that the controls do nothing more than send and receive property changes, they know nothing of the underlying data, logic, etc.  They simply show what their bound properties tell them to show.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer. +1

Comment: Well, maybe I don't understand MVVM, maybe I do.
Maybe it's just that I haven't expressed myself clearly enough.
The answer is, indeed, quite thorough, but it's an answer to some different question.
Sure I have these properties in my VM.
The issue is that - in my whatever limited perception - it's justified for my UC to have its own VM, separate from the host window's one. The UC's VM deals with some exclusive validation logic that is of no interest for the "main" VM.
So, my original question still stands: what's the best way to communicate the selected item from the main V/VM to the UC's VM.

Comment: I didn't intend that as a critisim; so I apologize if it came across that way.  It's difficult to answer your question directly as I don't know the specifics of your implementation, but the idea is the same.  It's up to the view models to communicate with each other, this may be through subscriptions to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface/event, through reactive extensions, or some other method.

Comment: Sounds good.
This would introduce a (weak) dependency between the 2 VMs - but I guess it's OK as long as it's abstracted by the subscription mechanism.
And sorry, I didn't mean to be so harsh in my reply either ;-)

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: on the second thought... I don't quite see how an individual ItemInfo VM can distinguish which Tab it belongs to, and what ItemRecord it should manage. After all, it's a one-to-many relationship (one Main VM vs. multiple ItemInfo VMs), so when the Main VM fires a notification, how an instance of ItemInfo VM is supposed to know it was intended for it - and not for another ItemInfo VM instance?
Looks like I will still need to pass some identification (e.g. ItemRecord.ID) to ItemInfo via binding from the Main.xaml - and here we come back to the original DataContext question...

Comment: @Alex What I do in situations like this, is I bind the TabControl (in your situation) to a collection of the respective ItemInfo VM.  So in a very large project I'm working on, I have a CustomerViewModel, that has a collection of Contacts and Locations.  Instead of binding the ListView I have to the actual contacts, I instead create a `ObservableCollection<ContactViewModel>` and bind the list to that.  When one of the contacts is selected for editing, the `ContactEditorView` is then bound to the `SelectedContactViewModel`.  Keeping all my logic etc in the VM.